# jsp code not executing in backbone.js view

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, backbone.js, backbone-views

I am trying to execute jsp code from my backbone view.
I am calling server side api from my Html as follows

### index.jsp (sample.js is included in this jsp)

```
%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"
         import="foo.*,java.util.List"

%>
<%

            Foo foo = new Foo();
            List<XYZ> xyzList = foo.getList();

%>
```

I am using backbone framework. My js code is as below.

### sample.js

```
SampleView = Backbone.ModalView.extend(
        {
        name: "SampleView",
        model: SomeModel,
        templateHtml : "<div ><span>Search </span>" +
                "<table border='1'>"+
                "<thead>"+
                "<tr>"+
                        "<td></td>"+
                        "<th>header1</th>"+
                        "<th>header2</th>"+
                        "<th>header3</th>"+
                "</tr>"+
                "</thead>"+
                "<tr>"+
                     "<% for(XYZ xyz: xyslist ){   %>"+
                     "<td><input type='checkbox' value='<%= xyz.getName()%>'></td>"+
                     "<td name='selected'><%= xyz.getName()%></td>"+
                     "<td></td>"+
                     "<td></td>"+
                    "<% } %>"+
                "</tr>"+
                "<tr>"+
                "<td><input type='checkbox' value='test'></td>"+
                     "<td name='selected'>test</td>"+
                     "<td></td>"+
                     "<td></td></tr>"+
                "</table><button id='select'>Select</button></div>",


                initialize: function(){
                _.bindAll( this, "render");
                                this.template = _.template( this.templateHtml);
                        },
        events: {
                "click #select": "select"
                        },
                select: function(){
                         //implementation

                },        
        render: function(){
                                $(this.el).html( this.template());
                return this;
            }
    });
```

The problem is, it does not execute jsp code. It displays only 'test' checkbox which is hardcoded and does not retrieve the list from server side. can you please tell me if I am missing anything here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The <% and %> tags used in JSP are also used by the underscore template engine.  Why are you using a template in your view, when you do not have any variables to supply?

When trying to run your code, the underscore template engine gives me an "Unexpected identifier", because the <% and %> does not contain valid JavaScript code for it to process.

Instead of

```
$(this.el).html( this.template());
```

you should insert the HTML string directly, like this

```
$(this.el).html(this.templateHtml);
```

Comment: Hi Werner, thanks for your reply. I changed the code as per your suggestion. But I am still getting the same result. It does not execute JSP code.

Comment: Could you provide the JSP where you instantiate your view?

Comment: THis SampleView is a modal dialog that gets called from another view.

Comment: var model = new DataNames();
var view = new SearchDataView({
     model:model
  });
view.render().showModal({
 x: event.pageX,
 y: event.pageY
  });

Comment: The problem is that the JSP code in your view template is never executed on the server.  When you access a JSP page, the java code in the page is executed on the server.  When your SampleView renders, it happens on the client, and its html is injected in a DOM element.  The server is never involved.

Comment: You could create a view and have its model updated with the result of an ajax request.  The ajax request could lead to a jsp which generate a list of some sort, preferably in JSON format.

Answer (score 1):

you have change using Underscore.js the _.templateSettings

for example to {{  your_variable  }} and no more <%= yourVariable %>

```
_.templateSettings = {
    interpolate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/gim,
    evaluate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/gim,
    escape: /\{\{\-(.+?)\}\}/gim
};

var Auto =  Backbone.Model.extend     defaults: {
        color : 'red',
        name  : 'ferrari',
        year  : 2008
    }
});

var AutoView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName : 'li',

    template: _.template('<strong>'
        +'{{ year }}</strong>{{ name }}'),

    initialize : function(){
        this.render();
    },

    render : function(){    
        this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );
    }
});

var auto = new Auto();
var autoView = new AutoView({model:auto});
```